# Google Map Marker v3 disappear and reappear only at certain zoom level

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I have a simple embedded map using fusion table. For some reason one of the markers disappear on the map and only shows up at certain zoom level. This is happening for newly added record.
I use fusion table query to load the map.

```
 function initialize() {
var myoptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.07621, 72.87766),
zoom: 10,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
  var locString = $.jStorage.get("loc");
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),myoptions);
  layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'Name'",
      from: '19uKyFR_QRg0oRyE0RetwgSIUbAJtOJCxu3vd3dE',
      where: "'City' = '" + locString + "'"
    },
    map: map
  });

}
```

This query shld return one marker. It only appears at certain zoom level

Answer (score 1):

FT servers need up to 1 minute to cache new records on all zoom levels. You might have hit this limitation.